# magmi import images not saved to the media/catalog/product

Tags: magento, magmi

I'm importing data using Magmi Image attributes processor v1.0.25 and using folder in magento with images. In csv is image named in format 65465446_M.jpg.
Import finnish with no errors, product have images, but image in admin is loading blank, like is in HTML code but did not exist physically on disk, if i find image in the Magento structure folder, there should be after import at media/catalog/product/... OR media/tmp/...  but there isn't, only manually uploaded images to another products.

In short, images are in the database, but image isn't move to the magento media/catalog/product/... folder, import from magmi finished without errors.

On server is running more Magento with magmi, there isn't problem.
It is known issue? Some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, problem was in general path for imported files "`Filesystem Path to magento directory`:", even if path worked for import and to load import csv file, not worked for images.

It is needed to correctly specify Magento "`Filesystem Path to magento directory`:" (in `Configure Global Parameters`)  it is relative to **`magmi.php`** file path, not a Magmi folder!

If you have this path of Magmi web interface `root/mydir/import/magmi/web/magmi.php` your "`Filesystem Path to magento directory`:" will be "`../../../../`" and your "Image search path:" can be "`media/import/images`" or any path relative to defined "Filesystem Path to magento directory:"

I make change for `Filesystem Path to magento directory`: to value "`../../../../`" (my Magmi is copyed to magento_root/subfolder/import/magmi/)

for CSVs base directory I've set up "mydata/imports" (this file is in magento_root/mydata/imports/)

and finally for pictures Image search path: "mydata/imports/import_images_folder/" (real path for each file is for example "`magento_root/mydata/imports/import_images_folder/someproductimage.jpg`")

and it works as expected

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was the magmi install path. I had it in a different folder not magento_root/magmi-importer. It puts the new files in magmi-importer/../media/catalog not magento_root/media/catalog.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a fix except for manually copying over the files?

Comment: You need to correctly specify Magento "Filesystem Path to magento directory:" it is relative to MAGMI.PHP file path, not a Magmi folder!.
If you have this path of Magmi root/mydir/import/magmi/web/magmi.php your "Filesystem Path to magento directory:" will be  "../../../../" and your "Image search path:" can be "media/import/images" ...

Comment: @LouisBataillard I moved the Magmi folder up to be in the magento root but Martin's solution would give you more flexibility.